# in chat application using node.js and mongodb , messages are saving for every page refresh. hot to solve?

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, socket.io

here is my js code for retrieving the user data which is already and now i am retrieving the same chats and displying it in my inner chat window

here is my code written in index.js file

```
 io.on('connection', function(socket){

  var query = Chat.find({});
   query.sort('-created').limit(4).exec(
   function(err,data){
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
    else{

        io.sockets.emit("chat history", data);
    }
   });
   });
```

and i am emiting the chat history and same is displaying in chat.js file as below

```
 socket.on("chat history", function(data){
   for(var i=data.length-1; i >=0; i--){
    displaymsgs(data[i]);
   }
  });
  function displaymsgs(data){
   feedback.innerHTML = "";
   output.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + data.username + ':</strong>' +
   data.message + '</p>';
   }
```

now i am unable to get the messages which are limit(4) and also messages are loading to database everytime when the page is reloads.

please give a solution where i am doing mistake and how to approach it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what exactly you want help with?  What is the observed behavior?  What is the desired result?